# Splitting values in application.properties

Tags: spring-boot, application.properties

I'm currently using spring boot for my app development. I need to extract environment variable which is comma separated. For ex I have env variable like prod,useast. How can I split the values and extract each value separately in application.properties.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Type-safe Configuration Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties) where you define the property as a `List<String>`. Spring Boot will split the comma separated value.